# gprof: symspec, member methods and demangled symbol names

Tags: c++, gcc, profiling, profiler, gprof

Consider the following example:

```
struct S {
    void foo() { bar(); }
    void bar() { }
};

int main() {
    S{}.foo();
}
```

I compiled it using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -pg main.cpp
```

Then I run it to get the `gmon.out` file. Once compiled, I invoked *gprof* with the following line:

```
gprof -q -b a.out gmon.out
```

Thus I found that there were two symbols:

```
[8] S::bar()      [9] S::foo()
```

Their names if not demangled (option `--no-demangle`) are (at least, on my laptop):

```
[8] _ZN1S3barEv      [9] _ZN1S3fooEv
```

Now I'd want to exclude a symbol from the call graph and it works fine using the command below:

```
gprof -q_ZN1S3barEv -b a.out gmon.out
```

Anyway, it doesn't work using the actual name once demangled, as suggested by the manpage that states about `symspec` without specifying that they have not to be demangled (it doesn't work neither using `S::bar()` nor `S::bar\(\)` and so on).

Is there any way to use the actual not demangled name in order to filter the call graph?

Comment: [*Alternatives to gprof*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771)

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't answer the question. :-)

Comment: Which is why it's a comment, not an answer :-) Whether or not you get an answer to your question, there is a big gap between expectation and reality with gprof.